# php destructor not working

Tags: php, oop, destructor

I am currently having problems with my php destructor code.

First, I have a basic html document like this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head><title>Home</title></head>
<body>

<?php include('Table.php');
$T = new Table();
?>

</body>
</html>
```

The problem is that the code "`new Table()`" should be echoing "`<table>`" during the constructor, and echoing "`</table>`" during the destructor.  My problem is I get the following code, and I don't know how to fix it:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head><title>Home</title></head>
<body>


<table>
</body>
</html></table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your destructor is only being called once the script has terminated, which is after your /html tag has already been output. What you are missing is simply one line to force the destructor to run before the script has completely ended: `unset()`

Try this:

```
<?php include('Table.php');
$T = new Table();
unset($T);
?>
```

For further reading, if needed: [Triggering Destructors Manually in PHP 5](http://www.devshed.com/c/a/PHP/Executing-Destructors-Manually-in-PHP-5/1/)